# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Camera module "crashes" Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22283/camera-module-crashes-raspberry-pi)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can the new raspberry pi B+ act as a usb sniffer?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22264/can-the-new-raspberry-pi-b-act-as-a-usb-sniffer)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Pi Headless: How to confirm that the Pi is shut down](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22579/pi-headless-how-to-confirm-that-the-pi-is-shut-down)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [RF24 communication with Arduino](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22490/rf24-communication-with-arduino)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Wi-Fi on a network with SSID Broadcast disabled](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22320/wi-fi-on-a-network-with-ssid-broadcast-disabled)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [4€ remote socket. The best idea ever?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22162/4%e2%82%ac-remote-socket-the-best-idea-ever)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to get in the raspbmc console if exit and esc does not work?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22250/how-to-get-in-the-raspbmc-console-if-exit-and-esc-does-not-work)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Raspberry Pi network can't be accessed outside of network](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/rasberry-pi-network-cant-be-accessed-outside-of-network)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Graphical Programming with WebGUI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22528/graphical-programming-with-webgui)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Using Qt5 on PiTFT](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22627/raspberrry-pitft-qt5)

**Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

Answer (score 5):

I feel there are many questions that are too specific and too poorly written to be of universal use. That is not necessarily a problem - specific questions do have a place here as well. Quite many questions would benefit from editing, and maybe we should try to make an effort to do so.

Comment: Second it. Although I'd refuse a too strong top-down approach in the moderation of the site it would be good to agree on how to improve the site and where to put our effort to (and/or update existing agreements thereof as well as make those agreements widely known). I find it hard to figure that out on Meta right now.

Answer (score -2):

I'd also like to find a way to get rid (answer/close/delete?) of old unanswered questions. When flipping through the "unanswered" stack one comes across questions with a biblical age that - if answered now - will likely never recieve any upvotes or acceptance, let alone be of help to the OP (as they are long since gone).

Comment: you should not care if the answer will help the original poster or not, think about people who have the same question and come to the site every day.

Comment: yeah sure, I get that (although the missing OP sometimes is a hindrance as you'll get neither feedback nor missing information). But if you parse through "unanswered" today and answer some questions they will not get any votes or become marked accepted. Thus if you parse through a month later you'll get the same questions again. This seems like a waste of time.